# range of numbers with fixed length, sequence names at end of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm looking to create an array of image elements and the filenames are all automatically generated as a sequence, like so:

```
File_00000.png
File_00001.png
File_00002.png
etc...
```

To generate my array of images, I'm using this:

```
const images = [...Array(143).keys()].map((image) => {
    return (
        <img
            key={image}
            src={require(`./images/File_0000${image}.png`)}
        />
    )
})
```

But as it reaches 10, I can't figure out how to generate the filename when it always has 5 trailing numbers, since it's sequential but at the end of the filename.

Comment: `String.prototype.padStart` and `String.prototype.padEnd` are your friends. `n => \`File_${n.toString().padStart(5, '0')}.png\``

Comment: You need to add zeros to the number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @ASDFGerte - thanks! I can't believe I haven't had to do this yet.